# fill in delimited sequence

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a file that contains a list of delimited sequence numbers as a record key.  I need to fill in the missing sequence.  So if I have

8
8.2
8.3.4.1

I need to add

8.1
8.3
8.3.1
8.3.2
8.3.3
8.3.4

I have come up with a few algorithms but they're all horribly complex and have too many cases.  Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to plod through?  I'm using c# but Java would do.

Comment: Why doesn't your result have 1,2,3,4,5,6, and 7?

Comment: The first digit is irrelevant in this case.  I just used "group 8" as an example.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Should I post code?  Sorry.  I'm new here.

Comment: If you have an answer, post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if my solution is easy to understand, but let's try. The idea is that we recursively insert missing sequences between existing ones.

First, you need to parse your file to create a List of items representing existing sequence. Every item should have reference to the next one (linked list idea).

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Item SubItem { get; set; }
    public Item NextItem { get; set; }

    public Item(int value, Item subItem)
    {
        Value = value;
        SubItem = subItem;
    }

    public Item CreatePreviousItem()
    {
        if (SubItem == null)
        {
            return Value == 1 ? null : new Item(Value - 1, null);
        }

        return new Item(Value, SubItem.CreatePreviousItem());
    }

    public bool IsItemMissingPrior(Item item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return 
            item.Value - Value > 1 
            || (SubItem == null && item.SubItem != null && item.SubItem.Value > 1) //edge case
            || (SubItem != null && SubItem.IsItemMissingPrior(item.SubItem));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value + (SubItem != null ? "." + SubItem : "");
    }
}
```

Assuming that sequences are delimited by new line symbol, you can use the following Parse method.

```
private List<Item> Parse(string s)
{
    var result = new List<Item>();
    var numberLines = s.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var numberLine in numberLines)
    {
        var numbers = numberLine.Split(new[] {'.'}).Reverse();

        Item itemInstance = null;
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            itemInstance = new Item(Convert.ToInt32(number), itemInstance);
        }

        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            result.Last().NextItem = itemInstance;
        }

        result.Add(itemInstance);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is a recursive method which inserts missing sequences between two existing ones

```
private void UpdateSequence(Item item)
{
    if (item.IsItemMissingPrior(item.NextItem))
    {
        var inBetweenItem = item.NextItem.CreatePreviousItem();
        inBetweenItem.NextItem = item.NextItem;
        item.NextItem = inBetweenItem;
        UpdateSequence(item);
    }
}
```

And finally the use case:

```
var inputItems = Parse(inputString);

foreach (var item in inputItems)
{
    UpdateSequence(item);
}
```

That's it. To see the result, you just need to get the first item from the list and keep moving forward using NextItem property. For example

```
var displayItem = inputItems.FirstOrDefault();
while (displayItem != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(displayItem.ToString());
    displayItem = displayItem.NextItem;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's fantastic.  I didn't even think of recursion, but the problem screams for it!  I must be going deaf in my old age. :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy ways (though not optimal for some cases) will be maintaining a set of existing keys. For each key in your initial sequence you can add all the preceding keys to that set. This can be done in two loops: in inner loop you add a key to a set and decrease last number of a key by one while the number is more than zero, in outer loop you decrease the length of a key by one.

And then you just need to output the set in sorted order.